# Consulta MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

estoy intentando hacer una consulta en `MongoDB`, y no me queda claro como hacerlo.

A través de la siguiente línea, obtengo lo mostrado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría saber si existe alguna forma de obtener tan sólo el campo en cuestión, es decir, "qfmSLTmr3tyZwykaA" y no todo lo que le precede.

O tratarlo de alguna forma a través de `javascript`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando realizas una busqueda en una colección y deseas excluir uno o varios campos puedes usar 0 para indicar no mostrar el campo:

```
db.colleccion.find({}, {"nombre campo no requerido": 0 })
```

para incluirlo usamos 1

```
db.colleccion.find({}, {"nombre campo no requerido": 1 })
```

---

El en caso de lo que realizas estas obteniendo todos los elementos de la colección pero únicamente muestras el campo "edificio", mientras que el campo "_id" lo excluyes:

```
db.terminales.find({}, {"edificio":1, "_id":0});
```

con este resultado:

```
"edificio": "qfmSLTmr3tyZwykaA"
```

---

**Si deseas obtener unicamente el valor (o los valores de un determinado campo)** se obtiene de esta forma:

```
db.terminales.find().forEach(function(row) {print(row.edificio);})
```

con esto obtendrás únicamente el valor del campo `edificio`

```
qfmSLTmr3tyZwykaA
```

Comment: Lo quiero hacer de una forma dinámica, así que partiría de no saber el id

Comment: El "id" te refieres a "qfmSLTmr3tyZwykaA"?

Comment: Sí. Básicamente quiero preguntar a través de javascript si una consulta equivale a otra consulta (mirando el campo de qfm..), haz algo. Pero claro, ambas consultas no comparten la parte precedente al campo. Además, esos valores se asignan de manera aleatoria cada vez que aparecen en mi base de datos

Comment: Tal vez no entendí correctamente pero lo que deseas es en lugar de obtener: "edificio": "qfmSLTmr3tyZwykaA", obtener únicamente "qfmSLTmr3tyZwykaA" ???

Comment: Sí, si fuera posible.

Comment: @MarioLópezBatres ok Mario he agregado respuesta, saludos.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Un placer amigos, saludos ᕦ /͠- ‿ ͝-\ ᕥ

Answer (score 0):

Sí se puede. Éste método de consulta se llama *Projection*. El método [`find`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find) acepta dos objetos como parámetro:

1. Campos de evaluación
2. Projection

Tu consulta se verá así al usar *Projection*:

```
db.terminales.find({}, { eficio: 1 } );
```

El entero es binario, es decir, acepta solo `0` y `1`. Por defecto, el `_id` será también seleccionado, en caso no desees éste comportamiento puedes obviarlo estableciendo `0` al `_id`:

```
db.terminales.find({}, { eficio: 1, _id: 0 } );
```